# Using CASE to select between two geometry functions?

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to cut holes in forest polygons, where there are lakes.

My PostGIS/PostgreSQL code look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE samp.forest_with_holes AS
  SELECT
    fo.objectid,
    (CASE ST_Intersects(fo.geom, la.geom)
      WHEN TRUE THEN ST_Difference(fo.geom, so.geom)
      ELSE fo.geom
    END CASE;) as geom
  from samp.forest as fo, samp.lake as la;
```

But I get the error message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CASE"
LINE xx:     END CASE;) as geom
```

Can anybody help me to see why this is not working - and please suggest a better way :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Correct way of using CASE:

   ```
   CASE 
     WHEN ST_Intersects(fo.geom, la.geom) THEN ST_Difference(fo.geom, la.geom)
     ELSE fo.geom
   END as geom
   ```
2. Better query:

   ```
   SELECT fo.objectid, COALESCE(ST_Difference(fo.geom, ST_Collect(la.geom)), fo.geom) AS geom
   FROM samp.forest AS fo 
   LEFT JOIN samp.lake AS la ON ST_Intersects(fo.geom, la.geom)
   GROUP BY fo.objectid
   ```

EDIT:

Coalesce gives you the first non-null input and since the difference between a geom and null results in null it will return the next value: 'fo.geom'. The ST_Collect aggregate is needed to make sure you cut multiple holes when there is more than 1 lake in the same forest polygon.

Comment: It's a good answer although you might want to explain why it is a better query.

Comment: ad. 1) I had to add an SELECT DISTINCT to get the result I want. But otherwise it works like a charm :-)

Comment: ad. 2) I have to agree... It works, but I don't know why? Plus, It doesn't include my fo.objectid column, and I can't figure out where to put it...

Comment: I've added a brief explanation, but please check the manual for Coalesce yourself as well. Also I fixed an omission in the query (ST_Collect) since you shouldn't have to use DISTINCT. It meant you were losing information when there was more than 1 lake in the forest polygon.